# Writing zipfile to disk works, but writing to memory does not. What is the difference?

Tags: python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am writing a CICD pipeline which requires packaging an aws lambda function into a zipfile, then uploading that zipfile as bytes via the boto3 sdk.

The following snippet works

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("lambda.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zipdir(local_lambda_directory, zf)

with open('lambda.zip', 'rb') as f:
    zipped_lambda = f.read()
```

with zipped_lambda being an object in memory that is ready for upload. However

```
zipfile_obj = BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_obj, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zipdir(local_lambda_directory, zf)

zipped_lambda = zipfile_obj.read()
```

ends with zipped_lambda being an empty bytes object. Why is this?

NOTE: the zipdir is just a function that recursively adds files from the passed directory (local_lambda_directory) to the passed file object (zf).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: In the second snippet, the cursor is at the end of the file after writing, so calling zipfile_obj.read() returns no data. Instead use **zipfile_obj.getvalue()** .